# Array of Objects returning Boolean value when used in for loop in a function

Tags: vb.net, multidimensional-array

so i am new to vb and learning to use vb with visual studio windows forms.

I have declared a new array of objects and assigned controls to each array element.
Now i am trying to use these array elements in a function to compare the properties of the control.

But as soon as i use my array in a for loop, the array elements are returning boolean values, instead of control as objects.

```
    For i = 1 To ButtonSubClass
        Object1 = ControlsCollection(ParentL2TabIndex, ParentL1TabIndex, i)
        If Object1 Is Nothing Then
        Else
            If Object1.Tag = 1 Then
                Object1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
                Object2.Visible = True
                Object2.Top = Object1.Top
                LocalBoolean = True
            ElseIf Object1.Tag = 0 Then
                Object1.BackColor = Color.LightGray
            End If
        End If
    Next
    If LocalBoolean = False Then : Object2.Visible = False : End If

    Return Nothing
End Function
```

ControlsCollection( , , ) is a three dimensional array which i have used to assign my controls from windows form.

Line5 of my code has an error, since Objects1 is returning a boolean in the for loop.

please help me to solve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's so much wrong here that it's hard to know where to start. If you are getting `Boolean` values out of the array then obviously you must be putting `Boolean` values into the array in the first place. You haven't bothered to show us the code that populates the array so we can't tell you more than that. The very first thing you should do is turn `Option Strict On`, which will help prevent you writing garbage code. Set it in the project properties and also in the VS settings, so it is `On` by default in all future projects.

Comment: Next, you should try declaring your array as a sensible type. If the array is intended to store controls then why would you declare it as an `Object` array? It should be a `Control` array at least and, if you only intend to store a specific type of control, e.g. `TextBox`, then it should be declared as that type. If you do that with `Option Strict On` then the compiler will tell you when you do something silly, like assign a `Boolean` where a `Control` is expected. It's then up to you to fix those errors, by using the correct data and data types.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Declaring the array as control has helped too. It seems somewhere in the middle of my code, I was unintentionally declaring some elements of array as Boolean. So saw the mistake and corrected the mistake. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here're just a couple of things to clean up your code. It's not an "answer" to your problem per se because it's not clear what you're trying to do.

```
For i = 1 To ButtonSubClass
```

I assume `ButtonSubClass` is actually an integer variable but there's no telling what it is and it's named terribly. Consider something like `ControlCount`. But you should probably really be using the `For Each` form, eg:

```
For Each control As Control in Controls
    ...
Next control
```

The internal code should look more like

```
If Object1 IsNot Nothing Then
    Select Case Object1.Tag
        Case 0
            Object1.BackColor = Color.LightGray
        Case 1
            Object1.BackColor = Color.DarkGray
            Object2.Visible = True
            Object2.Top = Object1.Top
            LocalBoolean = True
    End Select
End If
Object2.Visible = LocalBoolean
```

`LocalBoolean` is also a terrible, opaque name for a variable! Also, it will only ever get the value from the last iteration of the loop.

`Option2` isn't declared - what is it? Another control?

And why are you returning Nothing? That's pointless. Use a Sub or return something meaningful.

You really need to get your coding chops up I think; this is a long way from where you should be seeking assistance on SO.

Turn `Option Strict` and `Option Explicit` both "On" and preferably `Option Infer` "Off" and you'll be much better off.

Comment: `Option Explicit` is `On` by default and I can't really support turning `Option Infer Off`, although it doesn't strictly have to be `On` if you're not using anonymous types. The important change is setting `Option Strict On`.

Comment: `Option Infer` Off when starting out highlights newbie code problems; I think the OP is pretty unlikely to be using anons at this point

Comment: *"Option Infer Off when starting out highlights newbie code problems"*. I understand what you mean, but most of those problems would occur because you are allowing variables to default to type `Object`, but that can't happen with `Option Strict On`. Also, type inference only works when declaring and initialising at the same time, so wouldn't even be relevant to this specific issue and most others.  Anyway, more a matter of opinion than fact. Turning `Option Infer Off` is not inherently wrong.